# XML validation Using XSD Not Working in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

i have an XML, i need to validate it's not and the sequence, I've written some code but it's not working.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<TXLife>
  <UserAuthRequest>
    <UserPswd>
      <CryptType>NONE</CryptType>
      <Pswd/>
    </UserPswd>
    <VendorApp>
      <VendorName>AAA</VendorName>
      <AppName>BBB</AppName>
    </VendorApp>
  </UserAuthRequest>
</TXLife>
```

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="XMLSchema1"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/NewApplicationSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="TXLife">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="UserAuthRequest" minOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="UserLoginName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="UserPswd">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="CryptType" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Pswd"></xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="VendorApp">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="VendorName">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="VendorCode" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="AppName" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="VendorCode" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

C# code:

```
public void ValidateXML1()
        {
            List<string> _errors = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
                schemas.Add("http://tempuri.org/NewApplicationSchema.xsd", _sourceXsd);

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(_sourceXml);
                string msg = "";
                doc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
                {
                    _errors.Add(e.Message);
                    msg += e.Message + Environment.NewLine;
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

        }
```

As you can see that I've not supplied the `<UserLoginName>` in `XML` but in my `XSD` it's m`inOccures=1` , when i'm running this code it's validating and showing `error message =0` but i expecting error of not supplying `<UserLoginName>` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML file is missing the schema namespace.  Change it to

```
<TXLife xmlns="http://tempuri.org/NewApplicationSchema.xsd">
   ...
</TXLife>
```

Comment: XML is user input, so how can validate that one without schema?

Comment: Not sure that it will work, but try `schemas.Add("", _sourceXsd);`

Comment: If the XML document does not contain the namespace defined in the targetnamespace attribute within the schema it will not validate correctly. So you have 2 options change the schema or change the XML. You could change the XML in code once it is loaded, forcing the namespace into root element.